# Jquery Sortable Widget

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a box with a couple of entries based upon the ID of a table:

```
 <ul id="sortable">
 <?php do { ?> <li class="ui-state-default" id="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['entry']; ?>">
     <?php echo $row_Recordset1['PartNo']; ?></li>
 <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

I have defined the sortable jQuery:

```
 $(function() { 
   $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
 });
 var newp = $("#sortable" ).sortable('toArray');
```

and what I want to do is simply to pass this array to the next page in the process of recording on the database:

```
window.location.href = "quotations_build_itemsorder2.php?newp[]="+newp;
```

I keep getting an empty array.

Help .... please!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 0):

Since `newp` is already an array, you wouldn't pass it as `newp[]`, but just `newp`.

Also, `toArray` returns an array (presumably), and not a string.  You can't concatenate it to a string.  The easiest way to handle this would be to convert it to JSON:

```
"...?newp=" + JSON.stringify(newp)
```

Then you can use `json_decode` to get your array on the PHP side.

Comment: @JimElliott what does `JSON.stringify(newp)` contain?

Comment: var newp = $("#sortable").sortable( "serialize", {key: "sort"} );

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [sortable("serialize")](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) method:

```
var newp = $("#sortable").sortable( "serialize" )
```

You will have to rename the id's of your list items according to the format the serialize method requires (see documentation). Like this:

```
<?php do { ?> <li class="ui-state-default" id="sort_<?php echo $row_Recordset1['entry']; ?>">
```

EDIT: Also take a look at this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jStWW/)

Comment: I amended the code as you suggested but when I do a dump_var I get string(15) "[object Object]"

Comment: The addition of the {key: "sort"} option was unnecessary. But it still shouldn't show [object Object]. Please have a look at the jsiddle example I provided.

Comment: Got it to work by putting a form on the page and then assigning the hidden variable -  var data = $("#thesort").sortable("serialize");
    document.getElementById('newp').value = data;  Thanks!